# Write to plist file (In Particular row/Item)

Tags: ios, xcode, indexing, plist

I have a `.plist` file which have this structure,

[image]

I want to add or replace the Item 5. I am using this code

```
NSError *error ;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Introduction.plist"];

NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *comment = str;
[data replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:comment];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Introduction" ofType:@"plist"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath:path error:&error];
}
```

If I change `replaceObjectAtIndex:` to `5` it changes my plist structure, and I don't want that.

How can I insert/replace the text at the row 5 (Item 5) of particular Index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You structure has an array of arrays.

> [data replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:comment];

By this code you are replacing an array at index 1 with a string. Do you specifically need to insert to 5th index or do you just need to add it to existing sub array?

```
 NSMutableArray *subArray = [data[sectionIndex] mutableCopy];
if (!subArray) {
    subArray = [NSMutableArray array];
}

if (rowIndex<[subArray count]) {
    [subArray replaceObjectAtIndex:rowIndex withObject:comment];
}else{
    [subArray addObject:comment];
}

[data replaceObjectAtIndex:sectionIndex withObject:subArray];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

Access the subArray, make it mutable and add or insert at specific index. If you are trying to insert don't forget to include a check if the index is not greater than count of that array.